# Use different color for different values in drop down for excel files created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I need to create an excel sheet with a field status. It is a drop down with values 'High', 'Medium', and 'Low'. I need to show different colors when they select different values. I have implemented the drop down using [writeexcel](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel) gem. Here is my code:

```
worksheet.data_validation(count, 5,
          {
            :validate        => 'list',
            :source          => ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'],
          })
```

The drop down is working fine. But I want to specify a color for each selection. I can color the cell based on the selection of the dropdown, but what I need is different colors for different selections of the drop down. Any other gem having this implementation is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [write_xlsx](http://rubygems.org/gems/write_xlsx) gem is an updated version of [writeexcel](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel) that supports the newer Excel 2007+ XLSX format. It is by the same author and has the same interface but has additional features.

One of these new features is [Conditional Formating](http://rubydoc.info/gems/write_xlsx/Writexlsx/Worksheet%3aconditional_formatting).

You can use it to apply conditional formats to the same cell as the drop-down validation like this:

```
worksheet.conditional_formatting(count, 5,
    {
        :type     => 'cell',
        :format   => format1,
        :criteria => '=',
        :value    => '"High"'
    }
)

worksheet.conditional_formatting(count, 5,
    {
        :type     => 'cell',
        :format   => format2,
        :criteria => '=',
        :value    => '"Medium"'
    }
)
...
```

You will need to define the formats using the standard interface.

Note, write_xlsx is a port of the Perl module [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/). That module contains [additional documentation on the use of conditional formats](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING_IN_EXCEL). You should be able to convert the examples to Ruby easily enough.

See also my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks..just what I needed and I switched to `write_xlsx`

Comment: oh..I just realized you are the author of the perl library which this gem is based on!!! wow..so nice getting an answer from the author!!! thank you so much :)